# How do I add my configuration to Sublime Text 2's menu?

Tags: configuration, menu, sublimetext2, preferences

I've written a plugin for Sublime Text 2, which talks to a binary that I wrote. I expose the flags to the binary through as [settings file](https://github.com/JoshCheek/sublime-text-2-seeing-is-believing/blob/2167aaafa1b2979f729d33acfdda810c1650d9ce/Seeing%20Is%20Believing.sublime-settings), but I cannot figure out how to get the settings file placed into the menu bar.

[image: Where I want the settings]

[Here](https://github.com/JoshCheek/sublime-text-2-seeing-is-believing/blob/2167aaafa1b2979f729d33acfdda810c1650d9ce/Main.sublime-menu) is my best attempt so far.

[Here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/settings.html) are the docs on settings (not sure where the ones on menus are).

Comment: Why not just add it to the `Main.sublime-menu` file?

Comment: Because I don't think I can distribute that as a plugin (I'm assuming you're talking about the one in packages/Default, which is not part of my plugin)

Comment: Oh ok, I see.  I'll be following this.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, in order to add your own items to a menu, its original declaration must have a pre-existing `id` value, which must then be included in any package-specific menu expansions. For example, consider the default definition for `Preferences`:

```
{
    "caption": "Preferences",
    "mnemonic": "n",
    "id": "preferences",
    "children": [ ... ]
},
```

Notably, the `Settings – More` object in `Packages/Default/Main.sublime-menu` does **not** have an `id`.

```
{
   "caption": "Settings – More",
   "children": [ ... ]
},
```

You can prove this requirement yourself by adding an `id` value to `Settings – More` in the default `Main.sublime-menu` and including that `id` in your package's `Main.sublime-menu`, similarly to how `Preferences`' `id` is referenced. Your custom menu will then show up under `Settings – More`.

Based upon the exclusion of an `id` for `Settings – More`, I would assume that the creators of Sublime Text 2 did not intend for third party packages to be able to edit the menu in question. Also, note that the `–` in `Settings – More` is *not* a hyphen (`-`); that's not the cause of your problem, but I initially suspected that it might have been.

The standard practice for adding one's own package settings to `Preferences` appears to be inserting a new item into `Preferences -> Package Settings`, which can be accomplished with a `Main.sublime-menu` file like this:

```
[
  {
    "caption": "Preferences",
    "mnemonic": "n", // The mnemonics are for quick keyboard access
    "id": "preferences",
    "children": [
      {
        "caption": "Package Settings",
        "mnemonic": "P", // On windows, Alt+N (above) followed by Alt+P would open this menu
        "id": "package-settings",
        "children": [
          { 
            "caption": "Seeing Is Believing",
            "children": [
              {
                "command": "open_file",
                "args": {"file": "${packages}/Seeing Is Believing/Seeing Is Believing.sublime-settings"},
                "caption": "Settings – Default"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I would highly recommend referencing a menu-rich plugin's `Main.sublime-menu` to figure out what else you should include and how you should do it. For my research I examined both Sublime Text 2's `Main.sublime-menu` and [AdvancedNewFile's](https://github.com/skuroda/Sublime-AdvancedNewFile).